When Mo and Bo met Jo, Mo asked, “Are Bo and I both negative?” What can be deduced about Mo and Bo?
Beginner puzzle (suitable for people who are new to puzzle solving).

A certain city has two types of people: the ‘positives’, who only ask questions for which the correct answer is “yes” and the ‘negatives’ who only ask questions for which the correct answer is “no”. When Mo and Bo met Jo, Mo asked, “Are Bo and I both negative?” What can be deduced about Mo and Bo?

Attribution:  UK Pink Kangaroo 2022

It can be deduced that

 Mo is negative while Bo is positive

Reasoning:

 If Mo were positive, then the answer to his question would be yes, leading to a contradiction
 We now know Mo is negative, so the answer to the question is no, thus Bo can't be negative.

